# Function result varies on each run

Tags: python, palindrome

I have the following function that generates the longest [palindrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) of a string by removing and re-ordering the characters:

```
from collections import Counter


def find_longest_palindrome(s):
    count = Counter(s)
    chars = list(set(s))
    beg, mid, end = '', '', ''

    for i in range(len(chars)):
        if count[chars[i]] % 2 != 0:
            mid = chars[i]
            count[chars[i - 1]] -= 1
        else:
            for j in range(0, int(count[chars[i]] / 2)):
                beg += chars[i]

    end = beg
    end = ''.join(list(reversed(end)))

    return beg + mid + end


out = find_longest_palindrome('aacggg')
print(out)
```

I got this function by 'translating' [this example](https://www.tutorialcup.com/string/longest-palindrome-removing-rearranging-characters.htm) from C++

When ever I run my function, I get one of the following outputs at random it seems:

```
a
aca
agcga
```

The correct one in this case is `'agcga'` as this is the longest palindrome for the input string `'aacggg'`.

Could anyone suggest why this is occurring and how I could get the function to reliably return the longest palindrome?

P.S. The C++ code does not have this issue.

Comment: The "randomness" that you are observing stems from the nature of `set` since it is an unordered collection

Comment: Your code depends on the order of `list(set(s))`. But sets are unordered. In Python 3.4-3.7, the specific order you happen to get for sets of strings depends on the hash values for strings, which are explicitly randomized at startup.

Comment: I'm using `set()` to get the unique elements, I'll just try and find another way to do that

Comment: Using `set` is fine for finding the unique elements. Your issue lies elsewhere. You can ensure that the order is always consistent if you apply `sorted(list(set(s)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code depends on the order of `list(set(s))`.

But sets are unordered.

In CPython 3.4-3.7, the specific order you happen to get for sets of strings depends on the hash values for strings, which are explicitly randomized at startup, so it makes sense that you’d get different results on each run.

The reason you don’t see this in C++ is that the C++ `set` class template is not an unordered set, but a sorted set (based on a binary search tree, instead of a hash table), so you always get the same order in every run.

You could get the same behavior in Python by calling `sorted` on the set instead of just copying it to a list in whatever order it has.

But the code still isn’t correct; it just happens to work for some examples because the sorted order happens to give you the characters in most-repeated order. But that’s obviously not true in general, so you need to rethink your logic.

---

The most obvious difference introduced in your translation is this:

```
count[ch--]--;
```

… or, since you're looping over the characters by index instead of directly, more like:

```
count[chars[i--]]--;
```

Either way, this decrements the count of the current character, and then decrements the current character so that the loop will re-check the same character the next time through. You've turned this into something completely different:

```
count[chars[i - 1]] -= 1
```

This just decrements the count of the previous character.

In a for-each loop, you can't just change the loop variable and have any effect on the looping. To exactly replicate the C++ behavior, you'd either need to switch to a `while` loop, or put a `while True:` loop inside the `for` loop to get the same "repeat the same character" effect.

And, of course, you have to decrement the count of the current character, not decrement the count of the previous character that you're never going to see again.

```
for i in range(len(chars)):
    while True:
        if count[chars[i]] % 2 != 0:
            mid = chars[i]
            count[chars[i]] -= 1
        else:
            for j in range(0, int(count[chars[i]] / 2)):
                beg += chars[i]
            break
```

Of course you could obviously simplify this—starting with just looping `for ch in chars:`, but if you think about the logic of how the two loops work together, you should be able to see how to remove a whole level of indentation here. But this seems to be the smallest change to your code.

---

Notice that if you do this change, without the `sorted` change, the answer is chosen randomly when the correct answer is ambiguous—e.g., your example will give `agcga` one time, then `aggga` the next time.

Adding the `sorted` will make that choice consistent, but no less arbitrary.

Comment: I see, thanks for shedding light on that. However, using `sorted` results in the output being `aga` instead of `agca`. Any idea how that could be influencing the result?

Comment: It looks like sorting `count` by value and then setting `chars` to the keys of `count` seems to work for this example (but only for this example, and not for other ones)

Comment: @aL_eX `agca` is not a palindrome, so the fact that it doesn't return that is a good thing. But as I explained, the sorted order really isn't any more useful than any other random order here—it will work for some examples, and be wrong for others. It is at least reproducibly wrong, instead of randomly wrong, but that's not a huge win.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to type `agcga`

Comment: In that case I need to look at some other implementation, but I can't find any good ones in Python that don't require generating permutations for the input string and then checking if they are palindromes.

Comment: @aL_eX No, you just need to get this implementation right. Debug both versions to see whether they're going wrong. I edited the answer to show the most obvious error and the smallest change to fix it, but I can't promise that's the only error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some further examination and edit my question if I find something :)